# Mapping columns from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, mapping

Ok, so being an SQL novice I want to do a mapping from one column from one table in database A to another column from a table in database B and then join the two mappings in a third table in database B.

Example:
Database A, table A, has a column that contains types of vehicles:

> - 2 wheel motorcycle
> - 3 wheel motorcycle
> - 3 wheel car
> - 4 wheel car
> - 6 wheel car
> - 8 wheel truck
> - 12 wheel truck
> - 16 wheel truck
> - 18 wheel truck

Database B, table B does have a similar column for types, but they are more general:

> - '2 wheel motorcycle' from database A, table A maps to database B, table B 'motorcycle'
> - '3 wheel motorcycle' from database A, table A maps to database B, table B 'motorcycle'
> - '3 wheel car' => 'car'
> - '4 wheel car' => 'car'

...and so on.

In database B, table C, I want to have both columns visible, so it is possible to see what maps to what by looking at a row, example:

```
PK | detailed_types | general_types | column x  | column y | column z
3      3 wheel car     car
4      4 wheel car     car
```

But how do I go about this? 
I can select the result sets from A and B, but the mapping between them is where I have the problem.

Comment: Hi again
Thanks for your answers. However after trying your solutions I don't get the result set I expected. It occurs to me that I forgot something in the original question.

There are additional mappings such as:                                                                  
- 'Moped' => motorcycle
- 'Bus' => truck

And it seems that these missing the result sets.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help, A fuzzy join approach.. there are other ways

```
select * from detail a
    inner join general b on 
    a.descr like '%' + b.descr + '%'
```

detail and general are just the tables i made to mimic yours. This was my output

```
detail general
    2 wheel motorcycle, motorcycle
    3 wheel motorcycle, motorcycle
    3 wheel car,    car
    4 wheel car,    car
    6 wheel car,    car
    8 wheel truck,  truck
    12 wheel truck, truck
    16 wheel truck, truck
    18 wheel truck, truck
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT C (detailed_types, general_types) 
SELECT detailed_types, general_types FROM A..A
INNER JOIN B ON A.detailed_types like '%'+B.general_types
```

It would be better to impose primary keys on your tables, set up a foreign key, and join on the FK relationship.  But you didn't specify that, so I am basing my answer on your sparse set of parameters :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
SELECT A.detailed_types, B.general_types
FROM A, B
WHERE A.detailed_types LIKE '%' + B.general_types
```

or this:

```
SELECT A.general_types, B.detailed_types
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.general_types LIKE '%' + B.detailed_types
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I don't have 'enough reputation' to add comments so therefore this answer.

What I did was this:

```
--This puts the data from Database A to Database B:
INSERT INTO B (
detailed_types)

SELECT vehicle_types
FROM A
WHERE 
(vehicle_type = '2 wheel motorcycle' OR
vehicle_type = '3 wheel motorcycle' OR
vehicle_type = '2 wheel moped' OR
vehicle_type = '3 wheel moped' OR
vehicle_type = '3 wheel car' OR
vehicle_type = '4 wheel car' OR
vehicle_type = '6 wheel car' OR
vehicle_type = '8 wheel bus' OR
vehicle_type = '12 wheel bus' OR
vehicle_type = '8 wheel truck' OR
vehicle_type = '12 wheel truck' OR
vehicle_type = '16 wheel truck' OR
vehicle_type = '18 wheel truck');

-- Update the column and do the mapping like this:
UPDATE B.C SET general_types = 'motorcycle' where detailed_types = '2 wheel motorcycle'                 OR detailed_types = '3 wheel motorcycle';
UPDATE B.C SET general_types = 'motorcycle' where detailed_types = '2 wheel moped' OR detailed_types = '3 wheel moped';
UPDATE B.C SET general_types = 'car' where detailed_types = '3 wheel car' OR detailed_types = '4 wheel car' OR detailed_types = '6 wheel car';
UPDATE B.C SET general_types = 'truck' where detailed_types = '8 wheel bus' OR detailed_types = '12 wheel bus';
UPDATE B.C SET general_types = 'truck' where detailed_types = '8 wheel truck' OR detailed_types = '12 wheel truck' OR detailed_types = '16 wheel truck' OR detailed_types = '18 wheel truck';
```

So probably not the most effective SQL ever written, but it did the trick. Thanks for your answers all.